# I'm using Cognito + Spring security. There are any way to use authorization?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, amazon-cognito, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using spring Security and cognito for authentication and authorization.  I entered some custom roles via aws IAM and I would like to know if there was a method to grant controlled access to resources.  On the web I found some that set the cognito:groups as a role and used that, but they use deprecated classes and methods on it.  Is there any way to do this with the latest versions?

I tried to create a class:

```
package com.projectname.name.Configurations;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;


import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CognitoAccessTokenConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

  private final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter defaultGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();


  public CognitoAccessTokenConverter() {
  }
 
  @Override
  public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(@NonNull final Jwt jwt) {
      Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Stream
          .concat(defaultGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt).stream(), extractResourceRoles(jwt).stream())
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());           
      return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities);
  }
  
  private static Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractResourceRoles(final Jwt jwt) {
      Collection<String> userRoles = jwt.getClaimAsStringList("cognito:groups");
      //System.out.println("\n!!!!!!!!" +userRoles +"!!!!!!!!!!\n"); DEBUG
      if (userRoles != null)
          return userRoles
                    .stream()
                    .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
      return Collections.emptySet();
  }
}



 /* 
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationCode;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.


@Component
public class CognitoAccessTokenConverter extends OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken{

  
  private static final String COGNITO_GROUPS = "cognito:groups";
  private static final String SPRING_AUTHORITIES = "authorities";
  private static final String COGNITO_USERNAME = "username";
  private static final String SPRING_USER_NAME = "user_name";

}


@Component
public class CognitoAccessTokenConverter extends {

  // Note: This the core part.
  private static final String COGNITO_GROUPS = "cognito:groups";
  private static final String SPRING_AUTHORITIES = "authorities";
  private static final String COGNITO_USERNAME = "username";
  private static final String SPRING_USER_NAME = "user_name";

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> claims) {

    if (claims.containsKey(COGNITO_GROUPS))
      ((Map<String, Object>) claims).put(SPRING_AUTHORITIES, claims.get(COGNITO_GROUPS));
    if (claims.containsKey(COGNITO_USERNAME))
      ((Map<String, Object>) claims).put(SPRING_USER_NAME, claims.get(COGNITO_USERNAME));
    return super.extractAuthentication(claims);
  }
} */
```

how can I use this conversion in my spring security configuration?

```
package com.SSDProject.Booked.Configurations;

import java.io.*;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationSuccessEvent;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultRefreshTokenTokenResponseClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.IdTokenClaimNames;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {    

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize 
                .requestMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("max")
                .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login();
 

    
                

            return http.build();
    }
```

Help me, I tried to implements it and search everywhere. Some helps? Have you an idea?

Comment: I edited my answer with a very simple sample for configuring a resource-server with `cognito:groups`. Please give it a try and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

All of the [tutorials I maintain here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) are configured for Cognito (along with Auth0 and Keycloak). It covers both clients (with OAuth2 login and logout) and resource servers (REST APIs with basic **R**ole **B**ased **A**ccess **C**ontrol as well as more advanced control involving the accessed resource itself).

Depending on the resource returned by `/admin` endpoint being a JSON payload or a rendered template, your application is an OAuth2 resource server or an OAuth2 client, which have very different security needs and responsibilities (enough for Spring to provide with different Boot starters).

### Resource Server

Complete configuration with just `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` is pretty verbose and I won't reproduce it here. Refer to [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken) if you don't want to use ["my" starters](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistryPostProcessor expressionInterceptUrlRegistryPostProcessor() {
        return (AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry registry) -> registry
                .requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("max")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Auto-configuration is controlled with those properties

```yaml
scheme: http
origins:  ${scheme}://localhost:7443

server:
  port: 6443
  error:
    include-message: always
  ssl:
    enabled: false

spring:
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 30s

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      security:
        cors:
        - path: /**
          allowed-origins: ${origins}
        issuers:
        - location: https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_RzhmgLwjl
          username-claim: username
          authorities:
          - path: cognito:groups
            prefix: ROLE_
        permit-all:
        - "/v3/api-docs/**"

---
scheme: https

server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: ssl
```

You'd achieve the same conf by:

- removing the only bean in Java conf
- defining `permitAll: /**` in yaml
- decorating your `/admin` endpoint with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('max')")` (it is not `hasAuthority('max')` because I configured a `ROLE_` prefix in yaml like you do in your authorities mapper).

Side note: request to a resource server should arrive authorized (have an `Authorization` header) with a `Bearer` access token. Resource server only cares if the access token is valid and if he should grant the requested access to the resource based the token claims (contained in it or introspected from it). **Do not expect to query an OAuth2 resource server with your browser and to be redirected to login before accessing the resource**. Use a REST client (like Postman) which can fetch tokens from the authorization server and then issue authorized requests.

### Client With Login and Logout

You need login and logout in your Spring configuration in two cases only:

- the UI is rendered in a Spring application (Thymeleaf, JSF, ...)
- when implementing the **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend pattern with a spring application (`spring-cloud-gateway` with `TokenRelay` filter for instance)

Important note: clients with OAuth2 login are secured with sessions (not access tokens) and require CSRF protection.

Logout from Cognito is a little tricky because it does not implement the [RP-Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) spec, and, as a consequence, the `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` from the spring framework won't work. "My" client starters auto-configure a `LogoutSuccessHandler` flexible enough to invalidate a user session on Cognito:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain uiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin").hasRole("max")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();

        http.oauth2Login();
        http.logout();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

```yaml
scheme: http
ui-host: ${scheme}://localhost:${server.port}
cognito-issuer: https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_RzhmgLwjl
cognito-secret: change-me

server:
  port: 8080
  ssl:
    enabled: false
      
spring:
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 30s
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuer-uri: ${cognito-issuer}
        registration:
          cognito-confidential-user:
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-name: Amazon Cognito
            client-id: 12olioff63qklfe9nio746es9f
            client-secret: ${cognito-secret}
            provider: cognito
            scope: openid,profile,email

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      security:
        issuers:
        - location: ${cognito-issuer}
          username-claim: $.username
          authorities:
          - path: $.cognito:groups
        permit-all: 
        - /v3/api-docs/**
        client:
          client-uri: ${ui-host}
          post-logout-redirect-path: /
          oauth2-logout:
            - client-registration-id: cognito-confidential-user
              uri: https://spring-addons.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/logout
              client-id-request-param: client_id
              post-logout-uri-request-param: logout_uri
```

Refer to the tutorials for more advanced conf.

### Expose both a REST API and the UI to manipulate it

As security conf are very different for the two (Spring created different Boot starters for a reason), you'll have to create two `SecurityFilterChain` beans separated with a `securityMatcher` on the first in `@Order`. refer to [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui) for details.

### Implement the BFF pattern

For instructions to configure a Spring Cloud Gateway BFF (OAuth2 client with login, logout and `TokenRelay` filter) between an Angular app and a Spring Boot OAuth2 resource server, refer to this [other tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).

Comment: I'm curious why this did not answer nor was not of any help...

Comment: A good answer, has to be accepted as answer.

Comment: Considering how few are accepted or even up-voted, I must write very bad answers :D

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created the same PoC using SpringBoot 2.x and Java 17.
In my case I don't have any deprecation warning from my IDE, here my example:

```
  @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
            .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .userDetailsService(null)
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->
                    oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor())));

    return http.build();
}


private JwtAuthenticationConverter grantedAuthoritiesExtractor() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwt -> {
                String[] scopes;
                if (jwt.getClaims().containsKey("cognito:groups")) {
                    scopes = ((JSONArray) jwt.getClaims().get("cognito:groups")).toArray(new String[0]);
                } else {
                    scopes = ((String) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("scope", "")).split(" ");
                }
                return Arrays.stream(scopes)
                        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            }

    );

    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

Exactly which line is deprecated in your code? And what version of resource-server are you using? For me **spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server** is  2.7.5.

This is actually not an answer but I don't have the reputation for add comment to the question :)